# Skip one step of the loop if there is an NIntegrate::eincr message

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages

Is there a possibility of skipping one step of a loop if in this step there appears an error like `NIntegrate::eincr`? After skipping, the loop should go to the next step and continue evaluation.

Comment: Have you looked at `Check` and `Continue` in the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

As rm-rf remarks, this can be done with `Check` and `Abort` (and `Quiet` to keep things tidy):

[image: Mathematica graphics]